# Android RelativeLayout Button above TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

have 2 text views 1 next to another (using layout_toLeftOf attribute) and I'm trying to place a button above each one of the text views:
1) if I'm using above, alignLeft and alignRight attributes on the button, the button width and height enlarges to fit the size of the text views 
2) so I thought of using linear layout so it will fit to the size of the textview , and then place a button with layout_gravity="center", but it's not centered, it's aligned to the left.

Here is the code(its all inside a RelativeLayout):

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/countdown_hours_tv"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/countdown_hours_tv"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/countdown_hours_tv">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/plus_minus_button_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/plus_minus_button_size"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/plus_sign_button"
            android:onClick="increaseHourClicked"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/plus_minus_button_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/plus_minus_button_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/countdown_hours_tv"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/countdown_hours_tv"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/countdown_hours_tv"
        android:background="@drawable/minus_sign_button"
        android:onClick="decreaseHourClicked"/>
```

Comment: could you post your whole xml ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding the Button and the TextView inside a LinearLayout with vertical orientation. Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The LinearLayouts have the orientation attribute set to 'vertical' so all the views inside them will be aligned vertically. Then, if you want the TextView or the Button (or both) to be centred, add: android:layout_gravity='center'. Finally, because the LinearLayouts are in a RelativeLayout, I added android:layout_toRightOf='@id/layout1' to the second LinearLayout so the layouts will be aligned horizontally. Similarly, you could replace the RelativeLayout with another LinearLayout and set it's orientation te be 'horizontal'. It's the same thing.

Comment: I meant to add the explanation to the code in your answer by editing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using FrameLayout for putting one view on top of another, which is in your case a button on top of textView.